# How to prevent transformer generate function to produce certain words?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, generative-pretrained-transformer

I have the following [code](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/t5#inference):

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration

tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("t5-small")

input_ids = tokenizer("The <extra_id_0> walks in <extra_id_1> park", return_tensors="pt").input_ids

sequence_ids = model.generate(input_ids)
sequences = tokenizer.batch_decode(sequence_ids)
sequences
```

Currently it produces this:

```
['<pad><extra_id_0> park offers<extra_id_1> the<extra_id_2> park.</s>']
```

Is there a way to prevent the generator to produce certain words (e.g. `stopwords = ["park", "offer"]`)?

Comment: Are there any criteria that define a word as undesired?

Comment: @cronoik The only criterion is that these stop words are to be in the form of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after looking at the docs found out there is a [`bad_words_ids`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.27.2/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.GenerationConfig.bad_words_ids(List%5BList%5Bint%5D%5D,) parameter that you can pass in the `generate()`

given a bad word list you can create the id list using

```py
tokenizer(bad_words, add_special_tokens=False).input_ids
```

```py
input_ids = tokenizer("The <extra_id_0> walks in <extra_id_1> park", return_tensors="pt").input_ids
bad_words = ["park", "offers"]
bad_words_ids = tokenizer(bad_words, add_special_tokens=False).input_ids 
#[[2447], [704]]

sequence_ids = model.generate(input_ids, bad_words_ids=bad_words_ids)
#tensor([[    0, 32099,  1061,    19,     3,     9,   710,  1482,   550,    45, 32098,     8, 32097,  1061,     5,     1]])

sequences = tokenizer.batch_decode(sequence_ids)
print(sequences) 
#['<pad><extra_id_0> Park is a short walk away from<extra_id_1> the<extra_id_2> Park.</s>']
```

Notice how the word **"Park"** is appearing now. This is because the tokenizer identifies **park** (id **2447**) and **Park** (id **1061**) as 2 different tokens. This may depend on the tokenizer you use (there are case-insensitive tokenizers). If you don't want this to happen you can add Park into the bad word list as well.

[Colab demo](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1exQu6aBnatNu_3HzpLKV9YLljB6TM6dh?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't see why your answer is correct. Because the output of `print(sequences)` obviously has "Park" in it.

Comment: @neversaint because the tokenizer identifiers park and Park as two words. Park has Id 1061 while park 2447

Comment: @neversaint updated the answer with clarification